# Change in expected value by repeating an experiment

Tags: probability

I made this question myself which I think is a question on the conceptual level of expected values which can be solved only by logic. However being a beginner at expectancy, I am unable to solve this. I would greatly appreciate if anyone helps me in this.

Suppose the random variable associated to an experiment be X. Let the expected value of X be E. Now consider another event F which has probability p of happening. After the experiment, it is checked whether the event F occurs or not. If it does, the experiment is repeated. If it does not, the process in terminated.

My question is, by doing this process, does the expected value of the total experiment change or does it remain the same? Please give your reasoning, I prefer proper reasoning/useful hints rather than just the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the difference between expected value of a population, and the expected value of a sample size, and the expected value of a sample size with a biased stopping condition?

Comment: What do you mean by 'population'? Is it a subset of the sample set?

Comment: @CalvinLin I fail to see how the notion of "expected value of a sample size with a biased stopping condition" is even relevant.

Comment: @Did OP wants to stop the experiment when an event $F$ occurs, which seems to be the reason for believing that the "expected value of the experiment" (which I'm interpreting to be the average of the trials) will be affected by the stopping condition.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes the process will be stopped when F occurs. Sorry for the ambiguity in my question.

Comment: @HelloWorld The other question is, what do you mean by "expected value of experiment". Do you mean the expected value of the average of all trials in the experiment, or do you mean the expected value of the last trial?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes I mean the average of the total experiment, i.e all the trials combined.

Comment: @CalvinLin Suppose for example a dice is rolled. We know that the expected number of the dice will be 1*1/6 + 2*1/6 + ... + 6*1/6 = 3.5. Now I make a program in my computer which randomly selects any number between 1 and 2. If the result is between 1 and 1.5, I roll the dice again. If the result is between 1.5 and 2, I terminate the process. My question is, if the dice is rolled twice, will the expected value of the outcome of the two dice rolls combined change? This is just a special case, I am asking for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Formalizing what seems to be the setting the OP has in mind, we consider some i.i.d. random variables $X$ and $(X_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, and a random time $T$, independent of $(X_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, with geometric distribution of parameter $p$, that is, such that $P(T=n)=p(1-p)^{n-1}$ for every $n\geqslant1$.

The sample before $T$ is $(X_n)_{1\leqslant n\leqslant T-1}$. Its empirical mean is 
$$
M'=\frac1{T-1}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{T-1}X_n,
$$
which is undefined when $T=1$. Instead one might want to consider the sample $(X_n)_{1\leqslant n\leqslant T}$ up to time $T$ and its empirical mean 
$$
M=\frac1T\sum\limits_{n=1}^{T}X_n.
$$
If $P(X\in F)\ne0$, then $T$ is almost surely finite and $M$ is well defined. Furthermore,
$$
M=\frac1T\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty X_n\mathbf 1_{n\leqslant T},
$$ and each $X_n$ is independent of $T$, hence
$$
E[M]=E\left[\frac1T\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbf 1_{T\geqslant n}\right]\,E[X].
$$
Noting that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbf 1_{T\geqslant n}=T$ almost surely, one sees that 
$$
E[M]=E[X],
$$
thus, the stopping procedure does not modify the empirical mean.

All this assumes that $T$ is independent of $(X_n)_{n\geqslant1}$. Beware though that other stopping rules, such as $T=\inf\{n\geqslant 1\mid X_n\in B\}$ for some fixed $B$, might change $E[M]$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider flipping a coin. Our experiment will give us $+1$ if we get a Head, and a $0$ if we get a Tail.

The expected value of a flip is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Let the stopping condition be getting a Tail.

Then, we know that the expected number of flips is 2, of which only the last coin flip is a tail in each experiment, and hence the 'expected value' of the experiment is 1.

---

If the expected value of a trial is 0, and your stopping condition only depends on the value of the previous trials, then you can show that the 'expected value' of the experiment is 0. This follows by applying the linearity of expectation to the expected value of each trial. This is also known as a martingale (with no drift).

Comment: Ah, I understand your comment now.  I think I misinterpreted the question, I was calculating the expected value of the last trial.

Comment: @Tim It's not clear what OP is asking. Your interpretation of "expected value of last trial" could be valid, which might explain why Did doesn't like my comment of "biased stopping condition".

Comment: True, but reading the question a second time I think your  interpretation was correct.